# Include all objects in pointers in user

Tags: parse-platform

I am looking for an answer to this year old question in the old Parse Forums

https://parse.com/questions/include-key-inside-pfuser

Basically, I am wondering how to always have all object references in the current User loaded instead of having to first retrieve the object reference from the current User and then calling fetch on that object to actually retrieve its data.

In the Forum response, they say they might look into it but then it was closed. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is a known issue by Pars and it seams that they won't fix it. The worst part is that some times you will get the whole object without the need of the .fetch method.

This means that you can have your app working no problem, and one day suddenly it will stop working with no errors from Parse side.

You can check my commit on this mater here: [GitHub.com](https://github.com/davidgatti/IoT-Garage-Opener/commit/11ecc451f054c94c77cfd772453bf1b7cc5737ab)

It took me two days to figure this out, since even their documentation doesn't mention the need to use the .fetch method.